# Navigation from menu item

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get a menu item to navigate to another page but for some reason it wont let me do it. I'm a little confused as to how you go about it and any help is welcome!

Import here:

```
import { NavigationScreenProp } from "react-navigation";
```

Here is more code:

```
interface NotificationDropdownProps {
    navigation: NavigationScreenProp<any, any>;
}
```

Here is where function is called:

```
function renderNotification(notification: INotification) {
  return (
    <MenuOption
      onSelect={() => {
        if (notification.type == INotificationType.SYSTEM) {
          this.testFunction();
        }
      }}
    >
      <View style={[styles.notificationContainer]}>
        <View style={styles.iconArea}>
          <View style={[styles.iconCircle]}>
            <Icon
              name={this.getIconType(notification.type)}
              color={this.notificationColor(notification.type)}
              size={26}
            />
          </View>
        </View>

        <View>
          <Text>{notification.text}</Text>
          <Text>
            {this.getDate(new Date(notification.dateCreated))}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </MenuOption>
  );
}
```

Test Function:

```
testFunction(){
           this.props.navigation.navigate('NextPage')
};
```

Error:

```
undefined is not an object(evaluating'_this2.props.naviagtion.navigate)
```

Where the function is called:

```
<View>
  <Text>
    Notifications
  </Text>

  {this.props.notifications.length > 0 ? (
    <FlatList
      contentContainerStyle={{ borderRadius: 10 }}
      data={this.props.notifications.slice(0, 5)}
      renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderNotification(item)}
      keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
    />
  ) : (
    <Text>No Notifications!</Text>
  )}
</View>;
```

Answer (score 1):

try with an arrow function to avoid using the context of the function.

```js
testFunction = () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('NextPage')
};
```

Comment: thank you for your help but I get this error for that code:

Comment: Property 'navigation' does not exist on type 'Readonly<Props> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.ts(2339)

Comment: Can you put all the code and the errorin you post please, so that we will be able to fix your problem :)

Comment: Ive added some more code there, hope this can help

Comment: Are you sure you have the navigation prop in this.props ? Can you `console.log(this.props)`

Comment: I get a response of  [object Object]

Comment: Yes, this.props is an object haha but do you have the navigation prop in that object?

Comment: I'm new to this haha how can I do this :)

Comment: I've made an update to code still a problem with navigation prop, thank you for help so far